# Requiring all methods to match a type signature

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to type several classes that extend a BaseClass. I want to enforce a type requirement on the methods of those classes.

Ultimately, I need to be able to call arbitrary methods on instances of these classes knowing that the methods will have a particular shape. For reasons outside of my control, any method name might be called on instances of these classes and, if it's not undefined, the method will be passed a certain set of args.

My goal is to allow only methods with a type signature that matches those expected args. I want to avoid the situation where someone accidentally puts a helper function in with those methods of the expected type, which could result in that helper being called with args matching the expected type (which might be wrong for the helper function).

All the classes that extend BaseClass should be able to have data members of any type and zero or more methods, *but* any/all methods must be of the specified type.

I am really struggling with this one. I've been down a few rabbit holes with trying to use conditional types to define a NotFunction type, but I can't figure out how to use that in an index type, especially unioned with my valid function types.

Toy example:

```js
type GoodFunc = (a: string) => string;

abstract class BaseClass {
    className: string;

    constructor() {
        this.className = this.constructor.name;
    }
}

class ExtendedClass extends BaseClass {
    myString = 'this is a string';
    myObj = {someString: 5};
    myNum = 5;
    myMap = new Map();

    // All methods should be GoodFunc type
    // This is type GoodFunc, so no problem
    goodMethod(someString: string) {
        return someString;
    }

    // I want this to be a type error
    badMethod(someNum: number) {
        return someNum;
    }
}
```

[Toy example Playground link here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4g9nAJgMQK4DsDGUC8UAUAhgFxQDOwATgJboDmAlLgHzlW10DcAUN4QEYVKhTMCiYANoTJkoAIWkQAwlJlQA3tyjbxqsgDlCAWwikhHHlp2Y46IalFxK+Jpp3uowABbUyAOklpA2NoPG9fANt7R0o-dBCedwBfbhTuQLUAUQAPYAh0RAhEFSCoCFz8xFkFMmU9DSttIxAAZXZ6XCgAcnDZXyhCNhp6LsSdZoB5fgArTvUyOBM24bpSAFYksaaQfVQjTrWtqGaAWUIwTvQIAHcoM7AXS3cAemeoAEEJCWOIbyRZMheOCoCSIKD8aDwJBoLCecAQRpQV5QAAqPj6slAkFgCBQGEwABpyHAoOgSWBKHB+BIIEZEXRcSdfkDEPgFkt2qshhxXIj3JRfqhKOhiRyVkc0i83gBJKDXQjoMS9TwkiEDOHYiCUSmURH8QiIJl-VnsiC7IykdB7CGUXkeHQC4BCkWm80S1JAA)

Comment: Please put your example code in the question as plain text (see [ask] for more information, specifically "also copy the code into the question itself")

Comment: After you do that, can you articulate why `badMethod` should be disallowed?  Looks like a `NumFunc` to me. What am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Added code as plaintext and edited to clarify/fix.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NrKz3m) meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: That looks like exactly what I was going for. Thank! Looks like all I'll have to do is make sure that `implements` boilerplate makes it onto all the extensions.

Comment: Okay, I'll post an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to use a recursive generic constraint on `ExtendedClass`, of the form `class Cls implements Constraint<Cls> {}`, where `Cls` is assignable to `Constraint<Cls>` if and only if your class is properly written.  This sort of recursive constraint is known as [F-bounded quantification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification).

Here's one way to write that constraint:

```
type WithGoodFuncs<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? GoodFunc : T[K] }

class ExtendedClass extends BaseClass implements WithGoodFuncs<ExtendedClass> {}
```

The `WithGoodFuncs<T>` type makes a [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) version of `T` where you [check](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) each property to see if it's a function.  If the property is not a function, you leave it alone; otherwise, you replace it with `GoodFunc`.  So if `T` is, for example, `{a: string, b: number, c: ()=>void}`, then `WithGoodFuncs<T>` will be `{a: string, b: number, c: GoodFunc}`.

Then `class ExtendedClass implements WithGoodFuncs<ExtendedClass>` will compile without error if and only if every function-typed property of `ExtendedClass` is assignable to `GoodFunc`.  Let's test it out:

```
class ExtendedClass extends BaseClass implements WithGoodFuncs<ExtendedClass> {

    myString = 'this is a string'; // okay
    myObj = { someString: 5 }; // okay
    myNum = 5; // okay
    myMap = new Map(); // okay

    goodMethod(someString: string) { // okay
        return someString;
    }

    badMethod(someNum: number) { // error!
//  ~~~~~~~~~ <-- '(someNum: number) => number' is not assignable to 'GoodFunc'
        return someNum;
    }
}
```

Looks good.  All of the non-function properties are accepted, as is `goodMethod`.  And  `badMethod` has the desired error, which warns you that its type is not assignable to `GoodFunc`, which is hopefully enough information for someone to fix it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=43&pln=16&pc=1#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIHED2iAmAxArgOwMawLywAUAhgFywDOoATgJZYDmAlAQHxW0OMDcIJAI2o0SOULBwAbEpUqwAQjOgBhabNgBvYLB0S1lAHIkAttArDufbbpyIswjGMQ0irLbo+xQACzqUAdFIyhiZwhD5+gXYOTjT+WKF8HgC+wKlgUHAA6nQ+SKiYuJQAPAAqHIQasADaANKwDLAA1tDgiABmsKUAuhSldd2w0AAeoNBYKHKFYnR2sAD8CMjo2Hh9A7DpQeoAoqPjKNAoqsFD+xNyipQq+g3GkJLQpligcjl5y9Mle2MTRyeyDhaaw6YzgADKXCYBFgAHIInI-LASJx6ExYTxYAB6LGwRBNEjgEGwMEAeQEACsYVVKIhTJC0YwKABWTaYnF4glEjxggwYYww5ns3H4wnEsEAWRIkBhWGgAHdYFLIK5hZyxcTGMsJdAfKgiLT6VCmajuG5sSKucSPDRdRgaFgqHToAzLMT0h4BCQUDq9SgDc6+cYKFh+QJoDRzRyIzRnABCYAc2AAP1TabTsGKAFos3CA6YgyGwxHWPgOKHjOGaLCGnIsIhxME6IwEgJHl5EHD8itcLDrbpbaB7Y7DdAg0ldKlkkA)

Comment: The obvious shortcoming of this approach is that every sub class must implement the Constraint itself. i.e. if you forget to implement the constraint, you can write incorrect methods to your heart's content.